# use powershell to select all nested subdirectories which both contain and do not contain a specific file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, filter, where-clause

I am unable to return a list of (many) nested folders based on conditionals, and have tried for hours many different methods from searching online in documentation and sites such as this one.

I am trying the following line:

```ps
gci -recur -dir | ? { !(gci $_ -file -recur -filter √.txt) -and (gci $_ -file -recur -filter *.mp3) } | select name
```

and expecting to return a list of folders, which meet the following two conditions: contains at least one .mp3 file as a direct child, but does not contain a file named "√.txt"--as a direct child, i.e.:

-music
--artist
---album
----song1.mp3
would return just the album directory name or path, whereas:
-music
--artist
---album
----√.txt
----song1.mp3
would be skipped over, repeated for about 10 thousand variously nested albums.

Even more simply, I expect the following code to return a list of subdirectories which contain (as direct children) 1 or more .mp3 files, but it does not:

```ps
gci -recur -dir | ? { (gci $_ -file -recur -filter *.mp3) } | select name
```

It only returns the direct children (which are category folders such as "rock" or "jazz") of the current directory, despite the call to -recur.

What I would like to happen is I search a folder "music" which has many thousands of nested subdirectories, and return a list of the subdirectories (no matter how nested) which simultaneously contain (as direct children) mp3s but do not contain "√.txt" (as a direct child).

Hopefully this makes enough sense! Let me know if more info or clarity is needed.

Here is a snippet of the folder structure:

Directory: D:\music\rock\90s\Stereolab\albums:
1992 - Peng!
1992 - Switched On
1994 - Mars Audiac Quintet

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going astray by using -Recurse within the Where-Object condition, and maybe better to quote the filter strings for clarity (even if not strictly required).

Try this:
`Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter "*.mp3") -and -not (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter "√.txt") }`

Comment: this prints the following error for every album: Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\music\1996 - Hi Scores' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:53
+ ... urse | Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter "*.mp3") -and - ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\music\1996 - Hi Scores:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Do you get the same error with "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse" ?
I assume you are running the command from D: already, since we do not specify the starting path for Get-ChildItem

Comment: For testing, you could simply pipe the starting folder like this:
"c:\temp" | Get-ChildItem ...